# Netbios name lookups for LOCALHOST<20>

Tags: windows, networking

I've been looking at our network with wireshark and see a lot of our machines doing nbns lookups for LOCALHOST<20>

Now this means that the client machines instead of seeing localhost and just looking at themselves they are trying to resolve it by netbios, this is causing hundreds of lookups a minute by a lot of different machines on the network.

The lookups look like this:

[image]

And are sent to the network broadcast address 192.168.0.255

Is there a reason they are trying to resolve LOCALHOST with a netbios lookup?

Comment: Perhaps it's "localhost" followed by a space (ASCII 32, hex 20)? Something configured wrong somewhere?

Comment: Or it's trying to find a machine that is no longer on the network. Try `nbtstat -R` - "  (Reload)         Purge and reloads the remote cache name table". This will flush the NetBIOS cache.

Comment: This is happening on multiple machines and has been doing it for weeks, so they would of been rebooted plenty of times. the <20> means its looking for fileserver role.